# Resources$NotFoundException for String array with Robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric

In my Robolectric tests when calling `getResources().getStringArray(R.array.some_array_id)` I get a crash with `Resources$NotFoundException`.

This does not happen with other resource types, and it works in my app when running outside of tests.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was how I had defined the array in resources, I used:

```
<array name="some_array_id">
</array>
```

I needed to use:

```
<string-array name="some_array_id">
</string-array>
```

Either one works fine with the real Android SDK but only `string-array` works with Robolectric.